# SQL: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, left-join

```
left join
     (
     SELECT my_number, MAX(id) as id
     FROM table1
     GROUP BY location 
     ) newNum
     on newNum.Part = c.OtherPart

left join table2 t2 on t2.id = newNum.id and t2.site = a.site
```

Situation: I have the data fields (among others) my_number, location, and id in table1. In table2 I have the data fields (among others) id, site, date. I am joining those to other views/tables (c and a) that have some of the same data fields and my_numbers.

My goal: Each my_number has multiple id's and I want the greatest id value for each site. That is why I used group by site. 
Then I need to get the 'date' of the my_number based on the id, because the second table does not contain the my_number, just its associated id. 
There are a total of 3 sites, so I need the 3 greatest id value for each site. Then I want to get the 'date' of those 3 id values

Output table ex:

```
a.num   a.site  a.date  c.OtherPart T2.date
15            TN    1.1.16        17    3.19.16
15            FL    2.21.16       17    4.22.16
15            TX    1.7.15        17    3.21.16
```

Comment: I mean you know why it's giving you an error at least right?  You can't put a "GROUP BY location" in your subquery if you're not even going to reference it in your select.  You're basically telling it to group on values that don't exist and it's saying since it can't do that and since it has no other value to group on the query will error out because you have an aggregate function (MAX).  Can you please include the rest of your query?

Comment: if you have `SELECT my_number, MAX(id) as id` then you **must** have `group by  my_number`. (period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to do about your sql, you should only fetch columns which appears in `GROUP BY` or the other column in an aggregate function, anyway try this please;)

```
left join
     (
         SELECT my_number, id
         FROM table1 T1,
             (SELECT location, MAX(id) as id
             FROM table1
             GROUP BY location) TMP
         WHERE T1.id= TMP.id AND T1.location = TMP.location
     ) newNum
     on newNum.Part = c.OtherPart

left join table2 t2 on t2.id = newNum.id and t2.site = a.site
```

And you also can fix this error by following sql but may not what you want to do,

```
left join
     (
     SELECT location, MAX(id) as id
     FROM table1
     GROUP BY location 
     ) newNum
     on newNum.Part = c.OtherPart

left join table2 t2 on t2.id = newNum.id and t2.site = a.site
```

Answer (score 2):

When you put something like `max(column)` in a SQL query, the max function is operating on a set of values of column from a group.  If you've defined your query with a group by, such that the results are grouped, then every column (other than the one on which you are grouping) has multiple values.

In your case, `location` has one value (it's what you're grouping by), but `my_number` and `id` have multiple values.  If my_number is (1,2,3,4) and id is (5,6,7,8), you can display sum(my_number) or max(my_number) but obviously you can't display on a single row the 'number' my_number.  It is not a number, but a list.

This is what is meant when the error message says "SQL: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"  If you put the column `my_column` in an aggregate function (like `sum`) it will work, or if you add it to the group by clause it will work.